# php scientific notation significant digits

Tags: php, format, scientific-notation

In the PHP manual for function sprintf I find:

> e - the argument is treated as scientific notation (e.g. 1.2e+2). The
>   precision specifier stands for the number of digits after the decimal
>   point since PHP 5.2.1. In earlier versions, it was taken as number of
>   significant digits (one less).

Now I'm on PHP 5.4, but would like to format a number with scientific notation and indicate the number of significant digits instead of decimal places. Is there a function for this, or should I write it myself?

Comment: What's wrong with `sprintf`?

Comment: Looks like PHP won't take care of it for you, but you might not need to write it yourself. See [this PHP doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)and search for 'qwantastic'

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Provide an example input/output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I looked over the `(one less)` part, that's all I needed.
thanks for the help!

This means that I just had to decrease the value of the precision by one to get my function to behave the way I wanted.

See here for the function I came up with tot support scientific notation using sprintf

```
    function sn($number,$precision = 1,$case = 'e'){ //scientific notation
      $precision--; 
      $string = str_replace('+','',sprintf('%.'.$precision.$case, $number))." ";
      return $string;
    }
```

Comment: Try to be more specific with your answer. Provide code or else it's pretty useless to future users.